# More accurate version of Newton's Second Law?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, tensor-calculus

Since Force is a one-form (co-variant vector), is it more accurate to assert that $F = ma^ug_{uv}$ where $a^u$ is the acceleration vector, which is contra-variant, and $g_{uv}$ is the metric tensor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation $F = m a^\mu g_{\mu \nu}$ is notationally unclear.  You're right to note that tensor equations have to match types of tensors on both sides, but if we're being really careful about notation, then we have to note exactly what sort of tensor $F$ is.  If you mean $F_\nu$ when you write $F$, then it is true that $F_\nu = m a^\mu g_{\mu \nu}$, but it would be equally correct to write $F_\nu = m a_\nu$ or $F^\nu = m a^\nu$.  This is because in Einstein summation notation it is understood that $F^\mu = g^{\mu \nu} F_\nu$ and $F_\mu = g_{\mu \nu} F^\nu$.

Comment: Then in Newtonian Mechanics, do we consider $F_u$ or $F^u$ to be the force vector, since these are two different vectors (they are only same if the metric tensor is the kronecka delta)?

Comment: In the Newtonian mechanics you first learn when you are doing basic physics, it really doesn't matter because the metric is the Lorentz metric and you are only considering the spatial components of both the force and the acceleration.  If you add in the basic formalism of special relativity, then $F^\mu$ is called the force vector, but note that this is purely terminology.  Thanks to the metric, $F^\mu$ gives us $F_\mu$ and vice-versa.  The two objects ($F^\mu$ and $F_\mu$) are in dual correspondence, and so knowing one is sufficient to derive the other (with the help of the metric).

Comment: So $F^u = F_u$ in newtonian mechanics because the metric tensor is the spatial part of the Lorentz metric, right? Since even if we can find both vectors, if both vectors are different we would be using one of the vectors when doing force problems in Newtonian mechanics.

Comment: Yes, but it's really abuse of notation.  It's true because the spatial part of the Lorentz metric is just the Kronecker delta.  Really, $F^\mu = g^{\mu \nu} F_\nu$.  If we only care about the spatial part (i.e. $F^i$ where $i=1,2,3$) and we are working with the Lorentz metric (so $g^{i j} = \delta_{i j}$), then we get $F^i = g^{i j} F_j = \delta_{i j} F_j = F_i$, so the distinction doesn't matter in non-relativistic Newtonian mechanics.

Comment: Here I am using the convention where Greek indices like $\mu$ and $\nu$ range over all components of the tensor, but Roman indices like $i$ and $j$ only range over the spatial components of the tensor.

Comment: In spaces with a different metric, do we use $F_u$ or $F^u$ when doing force problems. Or if we use both, in which cases do we use the contra-variant vector and in which cases do we use the co-variant vector (just some examples)?

Comment: It doesn't really matter.  Thanks to the metric, they are just two sides of the same coin.  You can always just flip all the indices in an equation and it will still be valid.